How to debug Qt Creator's debugging helpers
Debugging in Qt Creator can be extended with custom debugging helpers:
https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-debugging-helpers.html
How can I debug the debugging helpers? E.g. is there a python snippet, which setups a breakpoint and where I can debug my custom qdump__Class(d, value) functions?

In lldb's built-in Python callouts (e.g. the summaries & synthetic child providers these QT debugging helpers are the lldb equivalent of) you just put: breakpoint() properly indented anywhere in your Python code, and when that line is executed, lldb will show the pdb prompt, and you can debug the subsequent Python code.  That should also "just work" for the QT helpers, except of course if the QT additions are doing anything funny to get the helpers to run.  In which case, you'll probably have to understand how these bits of code are getting run to figure out how to debug them.
